# "printf" on strings prints gibberish

Tags: c++, string, printf

I'm trying to print a string the following way:

```
int main(){
    string s("bla");
    printf("%s \n", s);
         .......
}
```

but all I get is this random gibberish.

Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because `%s` indicates a `char*`, not a `std::string`. Use `s.c_str()` or better still use, iostreams:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s("bla");
  std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I've tried it with std::cout and the compiler issues an error:
 binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string'

Comment: That's very strange. Which C++ implementation is this?

Comment: I've amended the code to be self-contained and compilable (and tested).

Answer (score 19):

You need to use [c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to get c-string equivalent to the string content as `printf` does not know how to print a string object.

```
string s("bla");
printf("%s \n", s.c_str());
```

Instead you can just do:

```
string s("bla");
std::cout<<s;
```

Comment: Thank... btw - why? printf does not know how to handle strings?
Is there another method I can use?

Comment: I've tried it with std::cout and the compiler issues an error: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string'

Comment: printf does not know how to handle c++ std::string s, it works on c strings(array of char with \0 to mark the end of string), note that because of backwards compatibility c++ c++ string literals, ie just "bla" instead of string s("bla") are c strings and not objects of the c++ std::string class.

Comment: Oh, Ok, it makes sense:) 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to print the string using "cout" when I switched from :

```
#include <string.h>
```

to

```
#include <string>
```

I wish I would understand why it matters...

Comment: From `include` to `include` ? What do you mean ?

Comment: The answer source included the data that Markdown removed. (BTW, @lazygoldenpanda, please don't post answers for things that should be comments or edits to the original question.)

Comment: string.h is a standard C header. Headers for most C++ standard library items don't have a .h  To access standard C headers in C++ code you should prefix a 'c'. e.g. <cstdlib> instead of <stdlib.h>. This is the intent of the C++ standards body to try to keep things non-colliding between C and C++.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just use

```
char s[]="bla";
```