# How to print a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, printf

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
#include <string>
string someString("This is a string.");
printf("%s\n", someString);
```

Comment: "Didn't work" - why not show us an error or what exactly didn't work? (Even though it's rather obvious in that case - but you might also have a compiler error as you don't import the `std` namespace)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634766/c-printf-on-strings-prints-gibberish

Answer (score 151, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
std::cout << someString << "\n";
```

or

```
printf("%s\n",someString.c_str());
```

Comment: I'd always prefer the former version.

Comment: it works better: std::cout << someString << "\n";

Comment: Why is C so annoying and complicated... Thx for that by the way

Answer (score 25):

You need to access the underlying buffer:

```
printf("%s\n", someString.c_str());
```

Or better use `cout << someString << endl;` (you need to `#include <iostream>` to use `cout`)

Additionally you might want to import the `std` namespace using `using namespace std;` or prefix both `string` and `cout` with `std::`.

Answer (score 13):

You need `#include<string>` to use `string` AND `#include<iostream>` to use `cin` and `cout`. (I didn't get it when I read the answers). Here's some code which works:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    string message("hi");
    cout << name << message;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't call "printf" with a std::string in parameter.
The "%s" is designed for C-style string : char* or char [].
In C++ you can do like that :

```
#include <iostream>
std::cout << YourString << std::endl;
```

If you **absolutely** want to use printf, you can use the "c_str()" method that give a char* representation of your string.

```
printf("%s\n",YourString.c_str())
```

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to use `printf()`, you might want to also:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: `#include <cstdio>`(How to print a string in **C++**)

Answer (score -2):

While using string, the best possible way to print your message is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  string newInput;
  getline(cin, newInput);
  cout<<newInput;
  return 0;
}
```

this can simply do the work instead of doing the method you adopted.

Comment: Simply not true. The biggest flaw here is the glaring security hole (buffer overrun!) but there are others.

Comment: yupp, that was serious issue. Thanx