# User Input in C++ like in Python

Tags: c++17

```
#Python code
user = input("Please enter your name \n")

print ("Your name is,", user)
```

How can I make this in C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322216/how-to-print-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly know what you want to achieve, but I think this is what you're looking for.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string user;

   /* ---- This part is in place of your python code --- */

   cout << "Please Enter your name"; cin >> user;
   cout << "Your name is" << user;

   /* --------------------- */

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer does not match the legitimate question, how to realize the input.
Consider this solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
T input(std::string message = "")
{
    if (!empty(message)) std::cout << message << " : ";
    T value;
    std::cin >> value;
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    auto i = input<int>("integer, followed by decimal point value");
    auto d = input<double>();

    if (std::cin) std::cout << "Gelesen: " << i << ' ' << d << '\n';
    else std::cout << "error reading input";
}
```

The `input()` function does not return a string like in Python, but a value of the type indicated in angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

To make a function that works as `input()` function in python for c++, you can use `std::getline()` to get input from the user, and returns it as a `std::string` .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Function that works like Python's input() function
std::string input(const std::string& prompt = "") {
    std::string user_input;
    std::cout << prompt;
    std::getline(std::cin, user_input);
    return user_input;
}


int main() {
    // Usage of input() function
    std::string user_input = input("Enter something :");
    std::cout << "User Input :" << user_input;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the cast operator template overload for `Input()`

Using templates and a package of parameters for `Print()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Input {
    Input(string s = "") {
        cout << s;
    }
template<typename T>
    operator T() {
        T v; cin >> v;
        return v;
    }
};
template <typename T> void Print(T t) { std::cout << t << '\n'; }
template<typename T, typename... Args> void Print(T t, Args... args) {  std::cout << t << ' ';  Print(args...); }

int main() {
    int a = Input();
    float b = Input("Enter float: ");
    char c = Input();
    string d = Input("How are you? ");
    Print("hello", a, b, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

[Test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odIza.png)