# got <null> using printf with string

Tags: c++, printf

When using printf for string, I got :

```
string key = "123";
printf("Value is %s \n", key);
```

> // output is: Value is < null >

But if I do it like this:

```
string key = "123";
printf("Value is: ");
printf(key.c_str());
```

then I get:

> // output is: Value is 123

So what I did wrong with

> printf %s

?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A string is not a char*. If you are using gcc, enabling warnings will cause the compiler to complain about runtime failures with the first call.

Comment: OK, the question is answered, but I'm just curious. why would the output be `Value is  ` in this case? Why not something else? (On my computer, the compiler warns that the program will crash, and it does.) Is is coincidence, does the value of `key` happen to look like a pointer that points to a zero byte?

Comment: @MR Lister: the first case, the output is <null> I typed it but then the editor hided it somehow. I just have updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` is a C++ class.  So this doesn't work because:

1. `printf` is a pure C function, which only knows how to deal with primitive types (`int`, `double`, `char *`, etc.).
2. `printf` is a [*variadic function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D).  Passing a class type to a variadic function leads to *undefined behaviour*.<sup>1</sup>

If you want to display a string, use `std::cout`:

```
std::cout << key << "\n";
```

If you simply *must* use `printf`, then this should work:

```
printf("%s\n", key.c_str());
```

`c_str` is a member function which returns a C-style string (i.e. a `const char *`).  Bear in mind that it has some restrictions; you cannot modify or delete the `string` object in-between calling `c_str()` and using the result:

```
const char *p = key.c_str();
key = "something else";
printf("%s\n", p);  // Undefined behaviour
```

---

<sub>1. Or possibly *implementation-defined*, I don't recall.  Either way, it's not going to end well.</sub>

Comment: thanks. std:cout also works but I would like to use printf to make it global.

Comment: @devn: What do you mean by "global"?  If you mean "also works in C", then stop there; `string` is C++-only.

Comment: I am a C# programmer. I am doing something with C++/CLI. In that C++ project, it contains many things in C as you pointed out they use printf everywhere instead of cout. therefore, I should use printf as well

Comment: @devn While I agree with the sentiment to use C++ output---`printf` is irremedialy broken---you should not mix the two on a single stream.  If the rest of the code is using `printf`, `putc`, etc., then you should **not** use `std::cout`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Could you elaborate. What problems could mixing C++ and C style output cause (assuming that `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio` has been called)?

Comment: @Mankarse `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio` has no effect on the behavior of `stdout`.  I suppose that if you used both `sync_with_stdio` and `unitbuf`, you could probably get away with mixing them, however, but with an enormous impact on speed (which may or may not be an issue).

Answer (score 3):

The token `%s` tells `printf` to expect a null terminating `const char*`, and you're passing it a `std::string`.

The correct way would be:

```
printf("Value is %s \n", key.c_str());
```

The C++ way would be to use `std::cout`.

Comment: If I had a penny for every time I've seen this problem, I'd have at least a dollar.

Comment: Just a nit, but `%s` tells `printf` to expect a `char const*`.  (But passing a `char*` is also fine---the standard explicitly allows type punning between pointer types which differ only in their cv-qualifications.)

Answer (score 2):

printf is C library function and requires C "string" (char*) for %s format. You have already discovered, that you can do cppstring.c_str() to get this.
Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634766/c-printf-on-strings-prints-gibberish).

Answer (score 2):

The C style would be

```
printf("Value is %s \n", key.c_str()); // printf does need a nullterminated char*
```

The C++ style would be

```
cout << "Value is %s " << key << endl; // cout can use std::string directly
```

Comment: great that you brought to me a better view of the difference between C and C++ style. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers: `printf` is a variadic function, and passing an object of class type which is not a POD is undefined behavior, and `std::string` is a class type which is not a POD.  Undefined behavior means, of course, that anything can happen, but this one is easy to detect, and a good compiler will at least warn about the error.

Answer (score 0):

cout<< string can work is bacasue of the String class has overloaded the operator "<<",so printf() certainly can't work!