# fprintf, strings and vectors

Tags: c++, c, string, vector, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ - printf on strings prints gibberish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634766/c-printf-on-strings-prints-gibberish)

I would like to write several strings to file . The strings are

```
37 1 0 0 0 0
15 1 0 0 0 0
33 1 0 0 0 0
29 1 0 0 0 0
18 1 0 0 0 0
25 1 0 0 0 0
```

I first would like to store each line as elements of a string array, then call the same string array and write its element to file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int writeFile() {

  char line[100];
  char* fname_r = "someFile_r.txt"
  char* fname_w = "someFile_w.txt"; 
  vector<string> vec;

  FILE fp_r = fopen(fname_r, "r");
  if(fgets(line, 256,fp_r) != NULL)   {
     vec.push_back(line);
  }

  FILE fp_w = fopen(fname_w, "w");
  for(int j = 0; j< vec.size(); j++) {
    fprintf(fp_w, "%s", vec[j]); // What did I miss? I get funny symbols here. I am expecting an ASCII
  }

  fclose(fp_w);
  fclose(fp_r);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're writing C code in C++. Stop it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format specifier `"%s"` expects a C-style null terminated string, not a `std::string`. Change to:

```
fprintf(fp_w, "%s", vec[j].c_str());
```

As this is C++, you should consider using [`ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) instead which are type-safe and accept `std::string` as input:

```
std::ofstream out(fname_w);
if (out.is_open())
{
    // There are several other ways to code this loop.
    for(int j = 0; j< vec.size(); j++)
        out << vec[j];
}
```

Equally, use [`ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) for input. The posted code has a potential buffer overrun:

```
char line[100];
...
if(fgets(line, 256,fp_r) != NULL)
```

`line` can store a maximum of `100` characters but the `fgets()` is stating that it can hold `256`. Using [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) removes this potential hazard as it populates a `std::string`:

```
std::ifstream in(fname_r);
std::string line;
while (std::getline(in, line)) vec.push_back(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case vec[j] is std::string object. But `fprintf` with `s` expects c-style null-terminated string.

```
for(int j = 0; j< vec.size(); j++) {
    fprintf(fp_w, "%s", vec[j]); 
}
```

All you need get pointer to c-style string from std::string. It's possible using `c_str` method:

```
for(int j = 0; j< vec.size(); j++) {
    fprintf(fp_w, "%s", vec[j].c_str()); 
}
```

In any case, you mixes C++ and C code. It's ugly.  Using of std::fstream is better.