# Newbie - convert char* to string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have function like below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

}
```

I want to find a character(dot character) in `argv[1]`. I tried to convert `char*` to string like below :

```
std::string para2="";
if(argc==2 && argv[1]!=NULL)
{
    para2 = string(argv[1]);
}
```

but `para2` show strange characters with print command and find function is not working properly. Please guide me how to find character in `char*` type.

Thanks

Comment: Show your *print* and *find* code.

Comment: if(para2.find(".jpg") >0       // it always return true

Comment: This is not C, I removed the incorrect tag. Please never tag as both C and C++ unless you really mean it.

Comment: ok, thanks for removing wrong tag

Comment: @unwind Your website is the best I've ever seen :D

Comment: @AslamKhan Can you put a more complete example in the question? The code in your comment is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes follow:

**Note #1:**

```
std::string para2="";
```

When you construct a string, the default constructor initializes an empty string, so you don't need the `=""` part: `std::string para2;` is just fine.

**Note #2:**

```
if(argc==2 && argv[1]!=NULL)
{
    para2 = string(argv[1]);
}
```

When you assign from `char*` to `std::string`, you can just use `operator=` overload, without the explicit `string` part:

```
para2 = argv[1];
```

---

Basing on some request in some comment to your question, you can use `std::string::rfind` to check for some extension, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::string param2;

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        param2 = argv[1];
    }

    std::cout << param2 << std::endl;

    if (param2.rfind(".jpg") != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "JPEG file." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are building your EXE as UNICODE.

Try setting the "Character set" to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" in Properties->General

Answer (score 0):

You may use the wrong printf. You can use std::cout to output the para2 but not use printf for the string type. As printf can only print out original type like int, double, float, ulong, char, char* etc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string para2="";
    if(argc==2 && argv[1]!=NULL)
    {
        para2 = std::string(argv[1]);
        std::cout<<para2<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can refer to ["printf" on strings prints gibberish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634766/printf-on-strings-prints-gibberish) and ["printf" on strings prints gibberish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634766/printf-on-strings-prints-gibberish).

If you want to find the specified string in char*, you can use strstr() function to do such things. And string::find can also do the find work, you can refer to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

For string::find function, the return value is size_t type. And the return value returns the position of the first character of the first match. If no matches were found, the function returns string::npos.

You should always use string::npos for the check condition but not with 0.

Comment: The correct way to use find is `if (para2.find(".jpg") != std::string::npos)`

Comment: Yes, the return value is size_t type, it is a unsigned int.
If no matches were found, the function returns string::npos. It does not mean string::npos is 0, you should use string::npos to check.

Comment: Oh, of course. `string::npos` is a very large positive number! I overlooked that too. And in fact, the test `para2.find(".jpg")` would return 0 if the string was equal to `".jpg"`

Comment: `std::string::npos` should be equal to `(std::size_t)-1` which is `0xFFFFFFFF`.